# Getting permission issue with the scope in API Management while Approving

Tags: sharepoint-online, ibm-api-management

Getting issue in API Management while approving API -

Issue - *[HTTP]:400 - [CorrelationId]:25ead09e-2016-0000-22ca-2805e5e18a16 [Version]:16.0.0.8727 - An OAuth permission with the scope Application.ReadWrite.All could not be found. Parameter name: scope*

In SharePoint Online after deploying Web-Part, then when I approve the API through API Management, I am getting this error for the **scope - Application.ReadWrite.All**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOz8O.png

Comment: If you have added the permission, you should add it to the scopes like this "scope": "Application.ReadWrite.All". If you have multiple scopes, you can separate them by space like this "scope": "Application.ReadWrite.All Directory.Read.All"

Comment: Did my comment solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks, @TonyJu for your response. I have added multiple scopes on my web-part. But, when I approve API from API Management then one API approved successfully and while I have trying to approve another API  then that issue was occurring.

Comment: Can you check the scopes in your access token by decoding it? https://jwt.io/